# Android forEachIndexed() function on Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, for-loop

Hey I'd like to ask if there is any way that I can use the Kotlins forEachIndexed() function for lists in Java? I searched everywhere but I couldn't find anything. I want to iterate over a list of ImageButtons and to each list item I want to set an Image from another list of bitmap image. So in Kotlin it would be:

```
buttons.forEachIndexed{index, button ->
    button.setOnclickListener{
    button.setImageResource(images[index])
     }
   }
```

The way I am iterating over buttons is

```
for(ImageButton button: buttons)
```

but I don't have any way to iterate over the indices. Can I somehow turn the Kotlin code above to Java?

Here is my code so far:pastebin.com/Rh9vcNbz

Comment: create a counter variable to store index and increase it in loop

Comment: I tried doing that I declared a counter like private int index = 0 and used it like: 

button.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(index));
index++; 

inside of the onClick activity for the button but the app just crashes.

Comment: It sounds like there's a bug in how you did that, so you should show us what exactly that code is and how it failed.

Comment: On the second run the code did work but now I realized that I have another problem. Before this code I tried to duplicate an ArrayList inside itself by just doing ArrayList.add(ArrayList) but that doesn't seem to work because the array should have 4 elements but when I iterate over it it just shows 2 elements. That's why it just breaks when I click 2 times to the screen.

Comment: Even if I use this method it would be pretty hard to set it up. Because I would have to check if the index count is lower than the ArrayList size and if it is Equal to I would have to reset it which then it would just add the same photos everywhere on click and not remember which photo it added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with Java and Kotlin for some years now and sadly I think that there is nothing in Java (atleast which is standard) that can deliver you something like Kotlin does with its **forEachIndexed**.

I mean if you look at the implementation of the "forEachIndexed"...

It is nothing more then this:

```kotlin
var index = 0
for (item in this) action(checkIndexOverflow(index++), item)
```

it basically creates an **int** variable for you, and increments it, while iterating over the List and invoking your Lambda.

If you still want something similar, which is still "hacky" - I wrote something for you, not that I want to say that it is perfect but does the job - and it is still generic.

New Classes:

```java
public interface IndexedAction<T> {
    void action(T item, int index);
}

public class ExtendedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public void forEachIndexed(IndexedAction<T> indexedAction) {
        int i = 0;
        for (T element : this) {
            indexedAction.action(element, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```java
      @Test // Robolectric Unit Test
    public void myTest() {
        ExtendedArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ExtendedArrayList<>();
        ExtendedArrayList<ImageButton> buttons = new ExtendedArrayList<>();
        Application context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
        int width = 200;
        int height = 100;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        Collections.shuffle(bitmapArray);
        ImageButton button1 = new ImageButton(context);
        ImageButton button2 = new ImageButton(context);
        ImageButton button3 = new ImageButton(context);
        ImageButton button4 = new ImageButton(context);

        buttons.add(button1);
        buttons.add(button2);
        buttons.add(button3);
        buttons.add(button4);
        buttons.forEachIndexed((button, index) -> 
            button.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(index)));
        }
```

Comment: Hey, great answer and I think it would work if I can implement it correctly. I tried doing that but instead of strings I am using buttons and another arraylist for bitmap images. I tried implementing your code to mine but it gives an error saying: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. I am adding elements to your list type with .add (example: buttons.add(button1). I dont think there is a problem with that. (here is my code:https://pastebin.com/Rh9vcNbz)

Comment: I tested mine actually in a Unit Test before posting it in here, I don't think that my "loop implementation" has an issue. 

Could you maybe post the full code that throws the IndexOutOfBoundsException in your Question?

Comment: Just added a pastebin

Comment: I can't run the code for me, because I am missing all the Firebase things, but I am pretty sure, that the mistake in your code is the following line

button.setImageBitmap(bitmapArray.get(index));


Those images, you put in this list, are being loaded from the Firebase Storage - could you debug, if they are actually in the list? 

I mean you iterate over a List with 4 Buttons in it, and then you make the assumption, that all those images have been loaded successfully so you have a 4 by 4 List.

(A list with 4 Buttons and another List with Images)

Comment: I updated my answer - I took your code and wrote something very similar, but just that my Bitmaps are not being loaded from the Firebase Storage (which could go wrong) and then you get an index out of bounds exception, because you are at button nr 1 and you want to load the image list at first index - but this list is now empty, because it could not get filled.

Comment: I realized that I never explained what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a memory card game(matching cards) which I am storing all of the images in a firebase storage. There is 44 cards in the storage and I am grabbing 2 cards and duplicating them to create a 2x2 matching card game. For this I am getting the 2 cards I need storing them in a temporary file and adding them to a bitmap arraylist where I want to randomly set them to cards.

Comment: Please also implement the failureListener when you load the images from the Firebase Storage, you should get an error here

Comment: Right now it is working kind of randomly. So it sometimes can retrieve the file and sometimes doesn't. But I don't think it shuffles the bitmap when I do Collections.shuffle(bitmapArray)

Comment: Well you need to think about, what to do, when you are not being able to load the pictures - if its a network ressource, it can have many "issues" - authentication, bad internet connection or no internet connection at all, permissions problems to access the given ressource and so on.

Anyway - your question was about a "forEachIndexed" in Java - I think the question itself is answered from my opinion.

Comment: Yes your answer really solved my problem. Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry for taking your time. Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't be sorry mate, we are all here in the same boat. I just wanted to focus on the question otherwise we could discuss here for the next 10 hours.

Comment: I guess you are right. I couldn't solve my problems so I turned the code into Kotlin and tried doing it there but it still gave me the same problem. (IndexOutOfBounds) So I think I am doing something wrong on retrieving the images from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Kotlin stdlib in the project but are working on a Java file, you can use Kotlin's `forEachIndexed` from Java. It's not particularly pretty but it's doable:

```
import kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt;

...

CollectionsKt.forEachIndexed(list, (index, element) -> {
    doSomething();
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

Comment: Yea also looks ugly, because of the static call and that I need to give the List as Parameter inside, but I mean, its an option. Thanks for sharing this too.